# arithmetic operator overload c++ for different types

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a class 'number' with one member 'm_value' of type int64_t. I already overloaded += operator, there is code:

```
number& operator+=(const number& right);
```

and it works fine with different types (e.g. int, int64_t, short, etc). In same way I overloaded + operator:

```
number operator+(const number& right);
```

But when I try to add class object with int64_t variable, it gives following error:

```
use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous (with operand types 'number' and 'int64_t' (aka 'long'))
```

Of course, I can overload the operator for other types, but I'm wondering if there is another solution for this problem and why, in the case of the first operator, the conversion from one type to another occurs automatically?

Thanks in advice!

UPD: Here is class header:

```
class number {
private:
    int64_t m_value;
public:
    number();
    number(int64_t value);
    number(const number& copy);
 
    number& operator=(const number& other);
 
    number& operator++();
    number operator++(int);
 
    number& operator--();
    number operator--(int);
 
    number& operator+=(const number& right);
    number& operator-=(const number& right);
    number& operator*=(const number& right);
    number& operator/=(const number& right);
    number& operator%=(const number& right);
 
    number& operator&=(const number& right);
    number& operator|=(const number& right);
    number& operator^=(const number& right);
 
    number operator+(const number& right);
    number operator-(const number& right);
    number operator*(const number& right);
    number operator/(const number& right);
    number operator%(const number& right);
    
    number operator&(const number& right);
    number operator|(const number& right);
    number operator^(const number& right);
 
    operator bool() const;
    operator int() const;
    operator int64_t() const;
    operator std::string() const;
 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const number& num);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, number& num);
};
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]. The question does not provide enough context to give a clear answer.

Comment: Possibly unrelated but `operator+` and all the rest that do not modify the object should be `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *implicit* conversions between your type and `int64_t` that go *both ways*. This is asking for trouble, possibly in more ways than what you have just discovered.

Assuming

```
number x;
int64_t y;
```

the expression `x + y` can be resolved two ways, as `x + (number)y` and as `(int64_t)x + y`. Neither one is better than the other, hence the ambiguity.

There are several ways to resolve this.

- Make one of the conversions `explicit`.
- Make *both* conversions `explicit` and do not use expressions like `x + y`.
- Make both conversions `explicit` and define (lots and lots of) overloads that take `number` and `int64_t` operands.

Comment: Thanks, it's solved my problem!